# MediaWiki how to declare the logo in LocalSettings 1.40

Tags: mediawiki

I have used the 1.23 MediaWiki version for many years. I now have to change my hosting provider and I have a problem to declare the site logo in `LocalSettings` 1.40. My logos images are in `/home/perso-wiki/public_html/images/wikilogo.jpg`

Could you tell me what should actually enter in my `LocalSettings` in using that configuration elements?

Answer (score 0):

Use [$wgLogos](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLogos). Depending on which skins you want to support, you might need to change your logo file.

Comment: I am sorry. I know I am to use $wgLogos. What I do not understand is the actual full entry I must put into LocalSettings when my logo file file is in (please use that sepcific config) "/home/perso-wiki/public_html/images/wikilogo.jpg"
Deep thx!